# Is there a map for the Assassin's Hideout?

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I'm pretty sure that the Assassin HQ in the far north of the map contains a "fast travel" location, and that it also has a place where you can dispatch your assassins on missions, but heck if I can find either of those things actually inside the base.

It seems like it's a simple building, but I'm constantly getting lost.  Is there a map somewhere of the assassin HQ, listing the various spots you can interact with?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't see how anyone should really *need* it, but since you asked I drew a sketch.  There are some places in the hideout where you can interact with only once (after reaching a certain point in the game), I don't recall where all these locations are exactly but they are of little/no importance so I've left them out.

Not to exact scale but close enough for illustrative purposes showing all the different interactive items in the hideout:

[image: the assassin's hideout]

Comment: I see Ezio keeps his utensils in the East wing.

Answer (score 9):

There is no in-game map, but I mapped it out for myself. It is obviously not to scale, but you can at least figure out where things are:

```
.----------------------------.
|               |   Tunnel   |
|    Armor      |  Entrance  |
`----  ------  -'-----  -----|--------- .
|         | 1                |  Books   |
|         |                  |   and    |
| Weapons                       Masyaf  |
|         |                  |  Table   |
|         | 2                |----------'
`---------'-----------.  .---'
                      |  |
.----------.          |  |
| Bomb     |----------|  |
| Crafting               | 
| Table    |----------|  |
`----------'          |  |
                      |  |
                      |  |
                     Street
                      Exit
```

1 - Mediterranean Defense table
2 - Assassins Guild faction board

Comment: Oh no!  Must... finish... my... drawings...  :)

Comment: @JeffMercado ASCII for the win. :D

Answer (score 1):

Generally there aren't any in-game maps for any of the buildings in *Assassin's Creed Revelations*, there are only the macro level maps of cities and terrain. The [*Assassin's Creed* Wikia](http://assassinscreed.wikia.com/wiki/Galata_headquarters) does not seem to have a map for the Galata headquarters either at this time.

Comment: For that matter, there wasn't an in-game map of the hideout in AC:B, either. I know I got turned around several times in the building before I learned my way around.

Comment: @TechParadox THE AC:B HIDEOUT MADE MY BRAIN EXPLODE EVERY TIME I HAD TO GO IN THERE

Comment: Sorry. I'm clearly still getting over the experience.